# I need to click this input only if it has "aria-checked ="true"

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I need to click this input only if it has "aria-checked ="true"

```
<input class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="mat-checkbox-131-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="true" style="" xpath="1">
```

Ruby:

```
aria_checked = true
if aria_checked = true
   impressora_etiqueta = "//mat-checkbox[@id='mat-checkbox-23']/label/div"
   page.find(:xpath, impressora_etiqueta).click
end
```

Comment: you can include the selector in query `[aria-checked]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want - simplest is probably

```
page.first('#mat-checkbox-23[aria-checked="true"]', minimum: 0)&.click
```

which will look for the first element with the given id and aria-checked = "true" and click it if one exists.

Note: the id in your test and sample HTML didn't match so I went the id from your test, adjust as needed. Also you have a class of `cdk-visually-hidden` shown -- If that's actually making the element not visible on the page, then this won't work and you'll need to add more surrounding HTML to your question with a better description of exactly what you're trying to do (you can't click on non-visible elements)